# extracting filename of email attachment python

Tags: python

I want to be able to download my email attachments from my email with the attachment filename as the filter. I have attached the code I am working on now but looks like there is something wrong with my code.

I suspect the issue is with the line:  if 'Star' in m.filename:
However, I am unable to resolve it.

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay

import pandas as pd

import win32com.client as win32

import datetime

import imaplib, email

import os.path

from datetime import date

import datetime as date

from win32com.client import Dispatch



outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder("6")

messages = inbox.Items

message = messages.GetFirst()

subject = message.Subject



for m in messages:

    if 'Star' in m.filename:

        attachments = message.Attachments

        num_attach = len([x for x in attachments])

        for x in range(1, num_attach+1):

            attachment = attachments.Item(x)

            attachment.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(r"X:\test\Schr",attachment.FileName))

        message = messages.GetNext()



    else:

        message = messages.GetNext()
```

Comment: Did you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate each attachment and then check for the file name

**Ex:**

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder("6")
messages = inbox.Items

for m in messages:
    if m.Attachments:
        for f in m.Attachments:
            if 'Star' in f.FileName:
                #Code....
```